# How do you use MVC's IDependencyResolver for things other than Controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject

I created a `NinjectDependencyResolver` class that is working great for injecting dependencies into controllers. I understand you can chain dependencies, but my problem is that I'm instantiating a class in the controller which then instantiates another class. That third class needs the other dependency injected such as:

```
public class MyController : Controller {
    MyObject obj;
    public MyController(IMyFirstDependency dependency) {
        obj = new MyObject(dependency);
    }
}

class MyObject {
    MyOtherObject otherObj;
    public MyObject(IMyFirstDependency dependency) {
        otherObj = new MyOtherObject(??????);
    }
}

class MyOtherObject {
    public MyOtherObject(IMySecondDependency dependencyTwo)
    {
        // do something with dependencyTwo
    }
}
```

What's the best way to inject dependencyTwo? Do I need to include it in the constructor for `MyObject` so I can use the chaining feature, or is there another way?

Answer (score 3):

You could make `MyObject` take this other dependency:

```
class MyObject {
    MyOtherObject otherObj;
    public MyObject(IMyFirstDependency dependency, IMySecondDependency dependencyTwo) {
        otherObj = new MyOtherObject(dependencyTwo);
    }
}
```

Now all you need is to register this dependency within the kernel:

```
kernel.Bind<IMySecondDependency>().To<MyConcreteSecondDependency >();
```

But normally you shouldn't need those 2 wrapper objects and doing some manual instantiations in their constructors (`MyObject` and `MyOtherObject`). You could directly work with the interfaces in your controllers. I really don't see any point of those objects. If they should act as some service classes aggregating your repositories, great, simply define an abstraction around them and have your controller directly take this service class:

```
public class MyController : Controller {

    private readonly IMyService myService;
    public MyController(IMyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    public ActionResult Index() {
        // you could use your service layer here with this.myService
    }

}
```

Comment: They aren't for a repository and it's a little complicated to explain. As I said in my question I understand I can add IMySecondDependency to the constructor of MyObject but isn't there a more general solution that doesn't require injecting everything into the controller or chaining dependencies?

Comment: What more general solution than using a service layer? I am afraid that from the information you provided I can't provide you with a better solution.

Comment: What if Controllers aren't involved at all? I guess I am trying to figure out if there is a way to use IDependencyResolver for objects without requiring the dependency to be injected into a Controller first. Maybe I need to learn more about how to use Ninject in a non-MVC app.

Comment: `What if Controllers aren't involved at all?` - I wonder how that would happen in ASP.NET MVC. Controllers are always involved in ASP.NET MVC (if you are doing it correctly) and that's where the composition of your dependencies start. If you have some objects in the wild which are never called by controllers (by who are they called then in an ASP.NET MVC application) you will have to handle the injection yourself - the IDependencyResolver cannot help you at all. This is designed to inject dependencies into ASP.NET MVC artifacts such as controllers.

Comment: Okay so I guess the answer to my question "is there another way?" is no.